# How to hange background Color of Selected Option in a Select Box

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What i need to do is to change blue color when i mouseover each option.

Here is HTML code,

```
<select id="color" class="colorchange">
    <option class="one" value="one" >one</option>
    <option class="two"   value="two" >two</option>
    <option class="three" value="three" >three</option>
</select>
```

I am really welcome if anyone help me in CSS solution..

Comment: Like `option {background-color: xxx;}` in css? see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sovkr8yj/)

Comment: Thanks, I need to change blue color when i mouseover each option..

Comment: @Prasanga So why not asking question regarding your expected behaviour???

Comment: Sorry for that, i cleared what i expected..

Comment: AFAIK, this can't be done with CSS...only Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, i ll make it plugin for this....

Comment: @Paulie_D AFAIK, this cannot be done in a cross browser way, webkit browser doesn't support mouse event on `option` element

Answer (score -1):

Simply:

```
option:hover { background-color: yellow; }
```

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry. Answer corrected.

Comment: Can you demo this working?